# Problems with formatting jurabib output in LyX

Tags: bibtex, lyx, footnotes, jurabib

I am having trouble using jurabib to create footnote citations in LyX. I followed the instructions for setting up LyX to use jurabib, see http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/HumanitiesLyX

Following the wiki recommendations, I added the following text to the LaTeX preamble (and applied it) in order to achieve an oxford-style format:

```
\jurabibsetup{%
titleformat=italic,%
titleformat=commasep,%
commabeforerest,%
ibidem=strict,%
citefull=first,%
lookat,%
oxford,%
pages=format,%
idem%
}
```

None of this formatting seems to have actually applied to the citations or to the bibliography output.  For example, titles are not italicized, nor are they followed by a comma.  In the end, I would like to be able to adjust the preamble to use Chicago-style footnote citations (and have the bibliography formatting in Chicago as well).

**The short and general question is**: how do I get the jurabibsetup part of my LaTeX preamble to actually apply to the document output?  Is this a problem with my preamble syntax or a problem with the formatting of my BibTeX entries?  Note: my current bibliography is in BibTeX and in the jurabib style. The .bib file for my bibliography was created as an export from Zotero. I do not receive any error messages when generating pdf output…I just don't get the output that I expect.  Here are some examples of entries from the .bib file that I am using, because I suspect that may be the underlying problem:

```
@incollection{lake_commitment_1998,
address = {Princeton, {N.J.}},
title = {Commitment Problems and the Spread of Ethnic Conflict},
isbn = {0691016917 (cloth alk. paper) 0691016909 (pbk. alk. paper)},
lccn = {Jefferson or Adams Bldg General or Area Studies Reading Rms GN496; .I595 1998 Main or Science/Business Reading Rms - STORED OFFSITE GN496; .I595 1998},
shorttitle = {Commitment Problems and the Spread of Ethnic Conflict},
url = {http://www.loc.gov/catdir/toc/prin031/97015031.html http://www.loc.gov/catdir/description/prin021/97015031.html},
booktitle = {The international spread of ethnic conflict : fear, diffusion, and escalation},
publisher = {Princeton University Press},
author = {Fearon, James D.},
editor = {Lake, David A. and Rothchild, Donald S.},
year = {1998},
keywords = {Conflict management., Ethnic conflict., International relations., World politics 1989-},
pages = {107--126},
annote = {{97015031David} A. Lake and Donald S. Rothchild, editors.ill. ; 25 {cm.Includes} bibliographical references (p. [351]-378) and index.},
annote = {The following values have no corresponding Zotero {field:SE} - 5}



@article{bates_organizing_2002,
title = {Organizing Violence},
volume = {46},
issn = {00220027},
shorttitle = {Organizing Violence},
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/3176194},
abstract = {In stateless societies, coercion is privately provided; violence is employed to engage in, and to defend against, predation. At best, violence results in mere redistribution; being destructive, it more often results in a loss of social welfare. When organized, however, violence can be socially productive; it can be employed to defend property rights, thereby strengthening the incentives to engage in productive activity. To explore how violence can be rendered a source of welfare, the authors develop a model of a stateless society in which people's rights to the product of their labor are secure only if they possess coercive capabilities. Using case materials and formal logic, the authors then compare this outcome with that obtained when private agents reward specialists in violence for defending property rights. In doing so, we plumb the role of the state.},
journal = {The Journal of Conflict Resolution},
author = {Bates, Robert and Greif, Avner and Singh, Smita},
year = {2002},
note = {5},
pages = {599--628},
annote = {{ArticleType:} primary\_article / Full publication date: Oct., 2002 / Copyright √Ç¬© 2002 Sage Publications, Inc.}
```

},